# type "null" is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast- nested json

Tags: flutter, nested-json

i want to retrive or parsing nested JSON data from rapidapi :
the recipe class should include basic data name,image
and contain object of rating{score}
and list of instruction{ position, text}
the structure of data in the image below

### JSON data in rapid api displayed in the image

[user rating in JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPFLf.png)
[Instruction list in JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t7xt.png)

## Recipe class

```
class Recipe {
  final String image;
  final rating Rating;
  final int? time;
  final int? personNum;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final List<instruction> instructions;
  //final int? instructions;

  Recipe({required this.Rating,required this.instructions,required this.personNum,required this.time,required this.name,required this.image, required this.description});

  factory Recipe.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    var list=json['instructions'] as List;
    print(list.runtimeType);
    List<instruction> instructionList=list.map((i) => instruction.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Recipe(
      image: json['thumbnail_url'],
      Rating: rating.fromJson(json['user_ratings']),
      time:json['total_time_minutes'],
      name: json['name'],
      description: json['description'],
      instructions: instructionList,
      personNum: json['num_servings'],
    );
  }
}
```

## rating class

```
class rating{
  int score;

  rating({required this.score});

  factory rating.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    return rating(
      score: json['score'],

    );
  }
```

## instruction class

```
class instruction {
  final int stepNum;
  final String text;

  instruction({ required this.text,required this.stepNum});

  factory instruction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return instruction(
      text: json['display_text'],
      stepNum: json['position'],
    );
  }
```

Comment: what is the output of this print(list.runtimeType);?

Comment: @Rationalist Null

Comment: can you show me print of approved_at? just above print(list.runtimeType)?

Comment: should because of List<instruction> instructions is dynamic type and seem like instruction object has diff attribute as well